# ServiceBehavior on client side

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, service-reference, servicebehavior

Why `serviceBehavior` part is not generated on client side automatically after `ServiceReference` tool in `Visual Studio` as endpointBehavior?

Comment: because serviceBehavior  is a _service behavior_ not a _client behavior_

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic So what? Endpoint configuration is based on service configuration. The same should be in serviceBehavior if I good understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wsdl.exe or "Add Service Reference..."  generate proxy classes, datacontracts & config based upon [exposed metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751951.aspx). Commons ways to expose metadata is by using a mex endpoint or exposing a wsdl.

Basically, Behaviors are simply not exposed. That's why you can't generate the same  endpoint behaviors on client side.

What is important here, is that many behaviors are "local settings only" (for a service OR for a client ). It does not tell to clients how to call the service, but how the service should run.